Show that the induced map on deRham cohomology is injective for $k \ge 0$
Edit: On Jack's suggestion, I wrote a better proof of this here.
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I have seen no proof for this problem in any textbook; all work is my own, so I want to make sure my own unique solution looks good. I'm having a surprisingly rough time with this one, primarily because I can't find that much in Lee's book (my primary reference) that I'm able to apply to solve it.

Question: Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth, finite covering map between smooth n-dimensional manifolds. Show that the induced map on deRham cohomology
$$ f^* : H^k_{dR}(Y ; \mathbb R) \rightarrow H _{dR}^k (X ; \mathbb R)$$
is injective, for all $k \ge 0$.

Answer: The strategy is to note that the pullback itself is injective. This means that if we have bijectivity within the image of the pullback, then we have guaranteed that our map is at least injective.
Firstly, we know that the property of being closed  is preserved:
$$ d\alpha = 0 \implies f^* (d\alpha) = f^*(0) = 0$$
Secondly, we can also tell that exactness is preserved
$$ f^* (d \omega) = d (f^* \omega)$$ which is clearly still exact.
Now, $f$ is locally a diffeomorphism, and thus the pullback on forms is locally isomorphic. We know that all closed forms are mapped to closed forms. There is a partition on sets and bijections within each partition. Then we must have a bijection between non-trivial, closed forms. Since the pullback itself is injective, this implies that the map is at least injective.

I feel there's something missing here.
Primarily, do I need to find a way to get the local behavior to induce global behavior, using the finite covering map as justification?
As a bonus, when the pullback behaves like a local isomorphism, is this a local isomorphism w.r.t it's image? I'm just having a lot of trouble understanding the consequences of these local diffeomorphisms and the effect they're having on the de Rahm Cohomology.

The issue here is that your argument is very local… while cohomology is everything but, so you should be suspicious. (I understand that there are ways to understand cohomology in a more local way, but these are a lot more advanced.) Try to run your argument for the complex exponential $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ (which is an infinite covering map) or $(0,10000) \rightarrow S^1$ (which is not a covering map, but a local diffeomorphism with finite fibres) to see what goes wrong.

Since you're using my smooth manifolds book as a reference, it's worth noting that Lemma 17.33 proves a very similar result. See if you can adapt that proof to the present case.

@JackLee Thanks a ton Jack! I swear I've read this chapter, so I must have forgotten about that example when looking back through for reference. I'm taking a look at the lemma your referenced. Sorry about that.
